# Suppose $a ≤ x_i≤ b $ for $i = 1, . . . , n. $ Show that $a ≤ \bar x ≤ b.$

Tags: statistics, means

Question is essentially, suppose a data set $x_i$ has values between (or equal to) $a$ and $b$, show that the mean lies in the same interval.

Obviously the mean lies inside the range however I'm struggling to 'show' this. Tried a few different routes with considering the summation of $x_i$ for $\bar x$ but not actually got anything valid.

Please help!

Comment: If $x_1\leq b$ then $x_1+x_2\leq b+x_2$ by replacing the $x_1$ with something bigger than it.  If further $x_2\leq b$ then you have $x_1+x_2\leq b+x_2\leq b+b$ by doing the same for the second term.  You don't have to do them one at a time, you could do a whole bunch of them at once to get that $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n \leq b+b+\dots+b$

Answer (score 0):

If $x_i\le b$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$, then $x_1+\ldots+x_n\le b+\ldots+b = nb$, so
$$
\bar x = \frac{x_1+\ldots+x_n}{n}\,\le\,\frac{nb}{n} = b.
$$
Can you do the same for the lower bound?

Comment: Ok, I follow. So for the lower bound it would be the same working with the inequality flipped and using a instead? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

Each element $x_{i}$ can be written as $$x_i =  a + c_i$$

For some constant $c_i$

Similarly Each element $x_{i}$ can  also be written as $$x_i =  b - d_i$$

For some constant $d_i$

Can you now find the upper and lower limit of these summation ??

Answer (score 0):

Let's see. I'll do the lower bound, since the upper bound can be done in a similar fashion. Since $a\leq x_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$, we have
$$a+a+\cdots+a\leq x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n,$$

where I have added up each of the inequalities $a\leq x_i$.

The left-hand-side of this inequality is $na$, so the inequality is the same as

$$na \leq x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n.$$

If I divide both sides of this inequality by $n$, I get
$$a \leq \frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n}{n},$$

but the right-hand-side is exactly the mean $\bar{x}$ of the data points, so in total

$$a\leq\bar{x}.$$